# VBA copy paste range every 7th row, 7 times

Tags: excel, loops, copy, paste, vba

Good afternoon,

After too many hours of researching the proper code for what I am trying to do, I am finally having to ask the experts here.  I am terribly new to VBA (but now hooked on conquering it!).

I am trying to copy a range of 3 cells of data I enter daily (I enter the data into columns J:L), then paste it 7 times, every 7th row below (so, I am copy/pasting Monday data to the next 7 Mondays, in their respective rows below).  Each day changes, and so will the paste location (Tuesday data will be copied, then pasted to the next 7 Tuesday rows below, etc.).  The data I enter will always be columns J:L.
Then, once the data is pasted, I have a button in place that uses that data, and clears it.  So, columns J:L are always clear, until I add the data to the next row of 3 cells.

Any help is appreciated, as I am simply stumped.  I tried several variations of "lastrow", but haven't found the proper coding that works for me (from piecing together info from here, but failing to make it work).

I tried to add a snapshot here, but apparently, I'm too noob for that even :/ 
The idea seems simple, so hopefully there will be a simple solution.

Thank you for your awesomeness!
Edited (sorry for making my first run at this site so difficult :/ )

```
Sub CopyPaste()  
'  
' CopyPaste Macro  
' copies and pastes range for 8 total weeks  
'  
Dim lastrow As Long  
lastrow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  
'  
    Selection.Copy  
    Range("J27").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J34").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J41").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J48").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J55").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J62").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J69").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Sub CopyPaste()
'
' CopyPaste Macro
' copies and pastes range for 8 total weeks
'
Dim lastrow As Long  
lastrow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'
    Selection.Copy  
    Range("J27").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J34").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J41").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J48").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J55").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J62").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Range("J69").Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
End Sub

Comment: Does the first Monday always start in J27? Where do you enter the data?

Comment: J27 was the row just for the Monday when I started trying to figure out the code to paste into the next 7 Monday rows. Once that date passed, the next Monday I would enter the data into J34, so i can copy there, and past that to the next 7 Monday rows.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your code suggests you want to copy from an unspecified cell to J27, J34 etc. Can you give a specific example of where the data starts and where it should go?

Comment: sorry, I am THAT new to VBA. This code was supposed to find the lastrow where i just entered the data in column J-L, for the starting point of what needs to be copied/pasted down.  The data starts in column J:L, for whatever row for that day of the week (i enter a number in each of the 3 cells in those columns).  I want to copy those 3 numbers, then paste them down below, skipping the blank rows until they get to the next day of the week row (every 7th row).  this should paste 7 total times.  this will display 8 rows of data in J:L, for the 8 Mondays, or Tuesday, or whatever day it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps. I foresee a problem though in that once you have copied values down the worksheet for say Monday, the last used row will be row 70 or something like that.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To 7
    Cells(lastrow, "J").Resize(, 3).Offset(7 * i).Value = Cells(lastrow, "J").Resize(, 3).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: so far, this is the best i've seen for what I am trying to do!  I have the code assigned to a button, so once i push it, i need the data copied, and pasted to the next 7 rows, and then done.  your code works well, but i have to keep moving it until i stop at how many rows to paste.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example please? I don't know what " i have to keep moving it until i stop at how many rows to paste" means.

Comment: stop the presses!  My apologies!  i was testing this code using F8 to run through the steps, and it was only pasting 1 row at a time.  I kept hitting F8 to run it through, to paste another row, etc.  Well, i should have just run the whole macro because it works perfectly!